# How expensive is a static ArrayList?

Tags: java, oop, static

Let's say I have an abstract class `Menu` and three subclasses `MexicanMenu`, `FinnishMenu`, `JapaneseMenu`.

Is more expensive having for each kind of menu a static `ArrayList<String> menu` or a non-static one?

What are the pro and cons of using a static menu against using an "instance" method?
OO design speaking I think both are equally compliant for the purpose.

Comment: `static` is not OO since it lives outside of the object.

Comment: thanks for your feedback @zapl however without classes I would not see any possible object.. so..

Comment: `static` uses less memory (if you have more than one object of a class type) because there's only one for each class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is more expensive having for each kind of menu a static

That is the basic need of method overriding.  And I'm not sure why you are going `static`

There is no side effect/ expensive memory leaks, as far as you are not concern about the thread safety.

I'm suggesting you to bind them to `instances`.

Comment: yes you right about the overriding, it was a bad example. I wanted just to know how expensive is considered a static arraylist

Comment: @IndeedItIs  Forget about expensiveness,That's almost negligible related to memory. If your design demands Just go for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare non static list in your abstract class and inherit it to all your subclasses.
If you want individual copy for each subclass then use non static list otherwise use static list.